ARCore: How to render the video on top of the detected images AR? [Without Using Sceneform]
I'm trying to develop an app that detects an image in AR and overlay a video on top of that image in AR. So far I have implemented the funvtionality of detecting the images using AugmentedImages functionality of ARCore. However, I tried a lot of things to overlay a video on top of the detected image in AR but none of them is overlaying the video properly.
Please provide me a way to overlay the video on the detected image in AR. I also got the center post of the detected image but could not find a way to attach a video player on the image.
Note: I don't want to use Sceneform since it is no longer maintained and archived. Hence I'm using ArCore and OpenGL to develop this app.
So far I have implemented the functionality of detecting an image using AugmentedImages functionality and able to get the center pose of the image. i'm expecting a video to be rendered on top of the detected image in AR.
I'm refering to this google's AR repository: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/augmented_image_java
An help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Be aware of the Sceneform-Android project and its successor SceneView-Android

Sceneform is deprecated that is why I refrain from using sceneform. However, I have not yet referred to Sceneview, thanks for the update I'll check it out. Meanwhile please let me know if there's any thing else I can implement fo the given functionality.

This is probably your best bet. https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android/blob/main/samples/ar-augmented-image/src/main/java/io/github/sceneview/sample/araugmentedimage/video/ExoPlayerNode.kt

If you are working directly with OpenGL ES, your big challenge is learning how to render a video in the 3D space.
I'd say start smaller, you said you already have the Augmented Image coordinates, try adding any virtual 3D object there. The other samples from ARCore should help you with this. Once you have that, exchange that 3D object with a static image (a texture) rendered on a plane. Ensure the location, size and rotation are as you expect in the 3D space.
A common pitfall when placing a typically 2D element on the 3D space is adjusting its size. Let's say you want to render a 200x200 pixels image in the 3D space, if you create a 3D object that is 200x200, that will translate to 200 real-world meters in the AR space! Maybe that's good for some use cases (let's say advertisement placed on a building) but probably that's not what you want for an indoor use case. Usually you'd set up the texture's size to be the same as your source image, and then you can scale up or down in the 3D space as you need.
Once you have the static image working, look into how to render a video. Depending where you are getting the video from, this will imply decoding each video frame and updating the content of your texture for every new video frame. Try to research some libraries that can do the decoding for you.

Thanks for the suggestion, I have started with rendering a texture on the image only. Let's see if it helps or not. Thanks!
